# Array of struct parsing in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe with one struct type column. Sample dataframe schema is:

```
root
 |-- Data: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

Field `name` holds column name and fields `value` holds column value. Number of elements in `Data` column is not defined so it can vary. I need to parse that data and get rid of nested structure. (Array `Explode` will not work in this case because data in one row belongs to one element). The real schema is much bigger and has multiple array field like 'Data' so my aim is to create a general solution which I will be apply to apply on similar structure arrays.
Example:

Sample data:

```
val data = Seq(
    """{"Data": [{ "name": "FName", "value": "Alex" }, { "name": "LName",   "value": "Strong"  }]}""",
    """{"Data": [{ "name": "FName", "value": "Robert " }, { "name": "MName",   "value": "Nesta "  }]} { "name": "LName",   "value": "Marley"  }]}"""
)
val df = spark.read.json(spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data))
```

Expected Result:

```
+-------+------+
|  FName| LName|
+-------+------+
|   Alex|Strong|
|Robert |Marley|
+-------+------+
```

As a solution I have create a UDF which I execute on whole `Data` column. As input parameters I am passing column name and a field name which I want to extract.

```
 val find_scheme_name_in_array = udf { (arr: Seq[Row], columnName: String) => {
    var value = ""
    arr.foreach(el =>
        if(el.getAs[String]("name") == columnName){
            value = el.getAs[String]("value")
        }
    )
    value
}}
```

The problem is that I am using variable `value` for storing  an intermediate result and I don't want to create a new a variable for each row on which my UDF will be executed.

The way how I am executing my UDF (That query generates an expected result):

```
df.select(find_scheme_name_in_array(col("Data"), lit("FName")).as("FName"),find_scheme_name_in_array(col("Data"), lit("LName")).as("LName")).show()
```

I would be happy to hear any comments on how I can improve the UDF's logic and some different ways of how to solve the parsing issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have solved the issue by substituting `foreach` loop with `find` method:

```
val find_scheme_name_in_array = udf { (arr: Seq[Row], columnName: String) =>
    arr.find(_.getAs[String]("name") == columnName) match {
        case Some(i) => i.getAs[String]("value")
        case None => null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this is helpful-

```scala
  val data = Seq(
      """{"Data": [{ "name": "FName", "value": "Alex" }, { "name": "LName",   "value": "Strong"  }]}""",
      """{"Data": [{ "name": "FName", "value": "Robert " }, { "name": "MName",   "value": "Nesta "  }, {
        |"name": "LName",   "value": "Marley"  }]}""".stripMargin
    )
    val df = spark.read
      .json(data.toDS())
    df.show(false)
    df.printSchema()

    /**
      * +----------------------------------------------------+
      * |Data                                                |
      * +----------------------------------------------------+
      * |[[FName, Alex], [LName, Strong]]                    |
      * |[[FName, Robert ], [MName, Nesta ], [LName, Marley]]|
      * +----------------------------------------------------+
      *
      * root
      * |-- Data: array (nullable = true)
      * |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
      * |    |    |-- name: string (nullable = true)
      * |    |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
      */

    df.selectExpr("inline_outer(Data)")
      .groupBy()
      .pivot("name")
      .agg(collect_list("value"))
      .withColumn("x", arrays_zip($"FName", $"LName"))
      .selectExpr("inline_outer(x)")
      .show(false)

    /**
      * +-------+------+
      * |FName  |LName |
      * +-------+------+
      * |Alex   |Strong|
      * |Robert |Marley|
      * +-------+------+
      */
```