# Extract DataFrame from nested, tagged array in Spark

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using Spark to read JSON documents on the following form:

```json
{
    "items": [
       {"type": "foo", value: 1},
       {"type": "bar", value: 2}
    ]
}
```

That is, the array items are *tagged* by the "type" column.

Given that I know the vocabulary of "type" (i.e. {foo, bar}), how do I get a dataframe out like so:

```
root
 |-- bar: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = true)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually curate the schema as below:

```py
>>> df2 = df.selectExpr("array(struct(items[0].value as foo, items[1].value as bar)) as items")
>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- items: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- foo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- bar: long (nullable = true)
```

Or a slightly more general approach using `filter`:

```py
>>> df2 = df.selectExpr("array(struct(filter(items, x -> x.type = 'foo')[0].value as foo, filter(items, x -> x.type = 'bar')[0].value as bar)) as items")
>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- items: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- foo: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- bar: long (nullable = true)
```

Or using `pivot`:

```py
>>> df2 = df.select(expr("inline_outer(items)")).groupBy().pivot("type").agg(
...     first("value")
... )
>>> df2.printSchema()
root
 |-- bar: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- foo: integer (nullable = true)
```

Comment: I suppose I can use `element_at` instead of `[0]` to avoid an error if there is no matching entry.

Comment: I adapted the answer with a third option as demonstrated in https://stackoverflow.com/a/63248480/647151.